# Proper way of designing a converter SPI using Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm the author of [little library](https://github.com/sargue/mailgun) to send email messages using the [Mailgun service](http://www.mailgun.com/).

The library has currently a very simple mechanism to generate rich mail body content using some sort of HTML DSL. I'm working on a next version of that where I want to offer a converter SPI so you can pass objects that get formatted as you want. I'm thinking about numbers, dates, currency values, etc.

I'm struggling with generics, wildcard types, bounds, etc. I think my problem is more of a general design than the specifics of generics usage. So my question is how should I design my SPI given the limitations of Java generics.

I have started defining the converter interface:

```
public interface ContentConverter<T> {
    String toString(T value);
}
```

There is a configuration object used throughout the library. There, the user is supposed to register instances of that interface using this registration method.

```
public <T> Configuration registerConverter(ContentConverter<? super T> converter,
                                           Class<T> classToConvert)
{
    converters.add(new Converter<>(classToConvert, converter));
    return this;
}
```

The `Converter` class is an internal class to encapsule the converter and it's class.

```
private final static class Converter<T> {
    private Class<T> classOfConverter;
    private ContentConverter<? super T> contentConverter;

    Converter(Class<T> classOfConverter,
              ContentConverter<? super T> contentConverter)
    {
        this.classOfConverter = classOfConverter;
        this.contentConverter = contentConverter;
    }
}
```

The `Configuration` keeps a list of converters.

```
private List<Converter<?>> converters = ...
```

Finally the configuration provides converters on demand.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> ContentConverter<T> converter(Class<T> classToConvert) {
    for (Converter<?> converter : converters)
        if (classToConvert.isAssignableFrom(converter.classOfConverter))
            return (ContentConverter<T>) converter.contentConverter;
    return (ContentConverter<T>) defaultConverter;
}
```

The default converter is just calling `Object.toString()`.

```
private final static ContentConverter<Object> defaultConverter =
    new ContentConverter<Object>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Object value) {
            return value.toString();
        }
    };
```

When the user is building the body message he can call any of these two methods to add an object using the configured converters.

```
public Builder text(Object value) {
    ContentConverter<?> converter = configuration.converter(value.getClass());
    return text(value, converter);
}

public <T> Builder text(T value, ContentConverter<T> converter) {
    return text(converter.toString(value));
}

public Builder text(String s) {
    [...] // this is where the content is really appendend
    return this;
}
```

But that doesn't work. The first method does not compile. I've tried different combinations but I think the problem is deeper, something about the erasure of the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the value parameter of the first `text` method generic. (You still need a cast for the class object):

```
public <T> Builder text(T value) {
    ContentConverter<T> converter = configuration.converter((Class<T>)value.getClass());
    return text(value, converter);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile because a cast for value is needed as well

Comment: @Jorge the value is a T

Comment: you're right, I didn't see you changed as well the parameter type.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're doing the correct castings, also for the value:

```
public <T> Builder text(Object value) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    ContentConverter<T> converter = configuration.converter((Class<T>)value.getClass());
    return text((T)value, converter);
}
```

And defining `T` as well in your first 'text' method

Anyway, note that your code will result in a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` because both `text` methods are calling eachother and will never obtain any output.

Comment: There is a text(String) overloaded method I didn't include in the example (I edited the question). It prevents the SO.